# Can't get my function to return the correct Boolean

Tags: python-3.x

```
def is_valid_walk(walk):
    n = 0
    s = 0
    w = 0
    e = 0
    for dire in walk:
        if dire == 'n':
            n+=1
        if dire == 's':
            s+=1
        if dire == 'e':
            s+=1
        if dire == 'w':
            s+=1

    return s == n and w == e and (n + s + e + w) == 10
```

I wrote this piece of code to determine if a walk would return me back to my original location and take exactly 10 minutes. During this exercise, when a direction to walk in is given, you walk one block. And each block would take exactly one minute. An example of a code that would return true for this is ['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']. However, when I plug ['n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'n', 's'] into the code it says the result should come out True, but It comes out False. Can someone help me understand what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. From what I can understand it seems like you are trying to make a walking simulation with keyboard input. It would be good if you provided more code such as what is 'walk' in your function and how is this variable defined.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are doing `s+=1` 3 times mistakenly. 
The code should be :

```
def is_valid_walk(walk):
    n = 0
    s = 0
    w = 0
    e = 0
    for dire in walk:
        if dire == 'n':
            n+=1
        if dire == 's':
            s+=1
        if dire == 'e':
            e+=1
        if dire == 'w':
            w+=1

    return s == n and w == e and (n + s + e + w) == 10

print(is_valid_walk(['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's']))
print(is_valid_walk(['n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'n', 's']))
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest another solution to this problem, using only two counting variables instead of four (in the code below the variable `d` is equivalent to your variable `dire`):

```
def is_valid_walk(walk):
  if len(walk) != 10:
    return False

  initial_x = 0
  initial_y = 0

  final_x = initial_x
  final_y = initial_y

  for d in walk:
    if d == 'n':
      final_y += 1
    if d == 's':
      final_y -= 1
    if d == 'e':
      final_x += 1
    if d == 'w':
      final_x -= 1

  return final_x == initial_x and final_y == initial_y

print(is_valid_walk(['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's']))
print(is_valid_walk(['n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'n', 's']))
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

It basically uses the coordinates, it first assumes that the position of the thing that's moving is `(x = 0, y = 0)` (technically this could be anything), and then it keeps moving along these coordinates (according to `n`, `s`, `e`, and `w`), and finally, it checks if the final position is equivalent to the initial position that you started with.